# Is it possible to set a conditional parameter type inside property get?

Tags: excel, vba

As an example, assume we have a vba class module with some different `Enum` types which matches the headers of different reports respectively.
Then, what i need is that depending on which report is active inside the object, a parameter of the `Property Get` would change its type to the corresponding `Enum` type.

Simplified version, It would look like this:

```
Public Enum Report1_Headers
   Field1 = 1
   Field2 = 2
   Field3 = 3
End Enum

Public Enum Report2_Headers
   FieldA = 1
   FieldB = 2
   FieldC = 3
   FieldD = 4
End Enum

Private MyReport as Variant

Private Sub Get_Report
   '...Do Something to Get Report
End sub

Property Get Report (FieldName as Report1_Headers)
   '...do something to Get value from Report
End Property
```

But i need it in a way "FieldName" would change its type to Report2_Headers dinamically, depending on the report loaded.

Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: No, it's not possible - be it in a `Property Get`, or any other procedure type. You need to review your design.

Comment: Even if that were possible it's not clear how you would *consume* an instance of the class - the code using the object would need to be equally "dynamic"

Comment: FWIW I would fully expect a procedure named `Get_Report` to, well, ***get*** me a report. Rename that to `CreateReport` if it doesn't return anything. Or make it a `Function` and get rid of the underscore. That said a function named `Get_Report` and then a property getter named `Report`, makes for a rather confusing API. What is `Report` meant to return? no return type is specified.

Comment: There is no `Report1_Headers` or `Report2_Headers` - only 1 through 4. Enums are not "strongly typed" in VBA in the sense that they are in other languages - they are all basically `Long`. Using `FieldName As Report1_Headers` is just syntactic sugar - you could pass it `42` if you wanted to and it would both compile and run that way.

Comment: As said, This is a very simplified example of the code concerning only the scope of this question. But for the sake of curiosity: The whole object downloads and parse diverse .txt files into a dictionary structure, this being the report. And yes, the Method used to capture the report in normal module level also has an enum type associated, which works perfectly. This is needed first to restrict and also because the structure of data inside each .txt file is quite different, each of it parsed by its own private sub inside the object class... Almost nothing to do with the specific question. Thx

Comment: To be clear: an enum doesn't restrict anything in any way. You could very well pass a `Report2_Headers` enum value to a procedure that takes a `Report1_Headers` parameter. Or you can give it any `Integer` or `Long` value, whether that value is a valid enum value. That's what "enums are not strongly-typed" means.

Comment: I'd just create a `ReportDefinition` class that is responsible for managing those differences. It's starting to sound like this is more of an X - Y problem, where the Y is the actual program design.

Comment: Have an `IReport` interface mandating a `Process` method or something - then have a `Report1` class that `Implements IReport` - you'll have an `IReport_Process` procedure for it. Then do the same in a `Report2` class that also `Implements IReport`, with its own `IReport_Process` procedure. Now your consuming code can work with any `IReport` and invoke its `Process` method, and each implementation deals with its specifics. You're trying to use enums to mimick polymorphism, while ignoring the actual polymorphism VBA allows you to do.

Comment: Mathieu, although your suggestion is quite good, this project may grow to read hudreds of different Reports. So would not be practical to have an individual class for each type of report since i can control the differences inside the same class module with private methods to parse them. But aside the parse structure, i want to restrict the read of the resulting dictionary to one simple method, with behavior changing inside its scope regarding the Parameter passed. But now I see that this is not possible the way I imagined. So I'm rethinking this design. Thanks for the good advices.

Comment: @Musicodelic Actually, I have successfully used parameters in a VBA class `Get` in some of my personal code (good design or not - usually for accessing data from an internal class collection). However, to allow the code to compile, you also need to request that same parameter in the associated `Let/Set`, if used (before the default `newValue` parameter). The order and symmetry of the parameter declarations is important. However, I don't know if it's possible to do it `"in a way "FieldName" would change its type to Report2_Headers dinamically"`, since I'm not sure what you mean by that.